# QMediaPlayer::metaData always returns QVariant(Invalid)

Tags: qt, metadata, qmediaplayer

I used Qt on MAC OS and try to retrieve the metadata of media. So i took the Qt's Media Player Example (Qt 5.8.0) and modified a little bit:

Instead of:

```
connect(controls, SIGNAL(play()), player, SLOT(play()));
```

i used:

```
connect(controls, &PlayerControls::play, player,
        [this]{
    qDebug() << player->isMetaDataAvailable();
    qDebug() << player->metaData(QMediaMetaData::Size);
    player->play();
    qDebug() << player->isMetaDataAvailable();
    qDebug() << player->metaData(QMediaMetaData::Resolution);
});
```

The results are:

```
false
QVariant(Invalid)
false
QVariant(Invalid)
```

**1st question:** why is the metadata not available even after the media started playing?

**2nd question:** i added some codes in the destructor:

```
Player::~Player()
{
    qDebug() << player->isMetaDataAvailable();
    qDebug() << player->metaData(QMediaMetaData::Duration);
}
```

Now the metadata is available, but no data is returned:

```
true
QVariant(Invalid)
```

Can anyone help me please?

---

Update Question 1:

Instead of

```
connect(controls, SIGNAL(pause()), player, SLOT(pause()));
```

i used:

```
connect(controls, &PlayerControls::pause, player,
        [this]{
    qDebug() << player->isMetaDataAvailable();
    qDebug() << player->metaData(QMediaMetaData::Resolution);
});
```

And after about 3-5 seconds of playing, the metadata is already available, but it also returns nothing:

```
true
QVariant(Invalid)
```

Comment: You should use `metaDataAvailableChanged(bool available)` signal

Comment: the question was: while `isMetaDataAvailable() == true`, getting `metaData` still returns a `QVariant(Invalid)`, how can i retrieve metaData of the media?

Answer (score 0):

This is not the exact answer for your question but this may help you. You can check which metadata available with this code:

```
QMetaDataReaderControl *c = qobject_cast<QMetaDataReaderControl*>(player_->service()->requestControl(QMetaDataReaderControl_iid));
if(c) {
    connect(c, &QMetaDataReaderControl::metaDataAvailableChanged, [c](bool) {
        qDebug() << c->availableMetaData();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I', not sure, but I think that qDebug cannot handle QVariant, you should use for example:

```
qDebug() << (player->metaData(QMediaMetaData::Title)).toString();
```